# Dagger 2 cycle injection

Tags: java, android, dependency-injection, stack-overflow, dagger-2

I have two singletone classes I'd like to inject them into Fragments, Activites, ect., but I've to inject them into each other as well. 
And at that point I allways get SO error.

```
public class AdverticumChecker implements IAdverticumChecker {

    @Inject BannerManager bannerManager;

    public AdverticumChecker(Context context) {
        IndexApplication.getApplication().getAppComponent().inject(this);
    }
}

public class BannerManager {
    @Inject IAdverticumChecker adverticumChecker;

    public BannerManager(){
        IndexApplication.getApplication().getAppComponent().inject(this);
    }
}
```

These are the modules

```
@Module
public class BannerManagerModule {

        @Singleton
        @Provides
        BannerManager provideBannerManager(){
            return new BannerManager();
        }
    }

@Module
public class AdverticumCheckerModule {
    private Context context;

    public AdverticumCheckerModule(Context context){
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Singleton
    @Provides
    IAdverticumChecker provideAdverticumChecker(){
        return new AdverticumChecker(context);
    }
}
```

I build the graph once at the Application class.
And here is the error:

> FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                             java.lang.StackOverflowError
>                                                                                 at
>   com.aff.index.adverticum.AdverticumChecker_MembersInjector.injectMembers(AdverticumChecker_MembersInjector.java:38)
>                                                                                 at
>   com.aff.index.adverticum.AdverticumChecker_MembersInjector.injectMembers(AdverticumChecker_MembersInjector.java:8)
>                                                                                 at
>   com.aff.index.dagger.DaggerAppComponent.inject(DaggerAppComponent.java:679)
>                                                                                 at
>   com.aff.index.adverticum.AdverticumChecker.(AdverticumChecker.java:50)
>                                                                                 at
>   com.aff.index.dagger.AdverticumCheckerModule.provideAdverticumChecker(AdverticumCheckerModule.java:30)
>                                                                                 at
>   com.aff.index.dagger.AdverticumCheckerModule_ProvideAdverticumCheckerFactory.get(AdverticumCheckerModule_ProvideAdverticumCheckerFactory.java:24)
>                                                                                 at
>   com.aff.index.dagger.AdverticumCheckerModule_ProvideAdverticumCheckerFactory.get(AdverticumCheckerModule_ProvideAdverticumCheckerFactory.java:8)
>                                                                                 at dagger.internal.DoubleCheck.get(DoubleCheck.java:46)
>                                                                                 at
>   com.aff.index.adverticum.BannerManager_MembersInjector.injectMembers(BannerManager_MembersInjector.java:67)
>                                                                                 at
>   com.aff.index.adverticum.BannerManager_MembersInjector.injectMembers(BannerManager_MembersInjector.java:11)
>                                                                                 at
>   com.aff.index.dagger.DaggerAppComponent.inject(DaggerAppComponent.java:704)
>                                                                                 at
>   com.aff.index.adverticum.BannerManager.(BannerManager.java:89)
>                                                                                 at
>   com.aff.index.dagger.BannerManagerModule.provideBannerManager(BannerManagerModule.java:21)
>                                                                                 at
>   com.aff.index.dagger.BannerManagerModule_ProvideBannerManagerFactory.get(BannerManagerModule_ProvideBannerManagerFactory.java:24)
>                                                                                 at
>   com.aff.index.dagger.BannerManagerModule_ProvideBannerManagerFactory.get(BannerManagerModule_ProvideBannerManagerFactory.java:8)
>                                                                                 at dagger.internal.DoubleCheck.get(DoubleCheck.java:46)
>                                                                                 at
>   com.aff.index.adverticum.AdverticumChecker_MembersInjector.injectMembers(AdverticumChecker_MembersInjector.java:39)
>                                                                                 at
>   com.aff.index.adverticum.AdverticumChecker_MembersInjector.injectMembers(AdverticumChecker_MembersInjector.java:8)
>                                                                                 at
>   com.aff.index.dagger.DaggerAppComponent.inject(DaggerAppComponent.java:679)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First things first, this...

```
@Singleton
@Provides
IAdverticumChecker provideAdverticumChecker(){
    return new AdverticumChecker(context);
}
...
public AdverticumChecker(Context context) {
    IndexApplication.getApplication().getAppComponent().inject(this);
}
```

circumvents what DI stands for, basically inject dependencies, rather than letting some static accessor in your constructor inject them magically - this way `AdvertiumChecker` is almost impossible to test! List all your dependencies as constructor arguments instead and do it like this:

```
@Singleton
@Provides
IAdverticumChecker provideAdverticumChecker(BannerManager bannerManager){
    return new AdverticumChecker(bannerManager);
}
...
private BannerManager mBannerManager;
public AdverticumChecker(BannerManager bannerManager) {
    mBannerManager = bannerManager;
}
```

Dagger will automatically fill the gaps for you here and construct a proper graph.

Secondly, in case the construction of `BannerManager` is dependent on an instance of `IAdvertiumChecker`, you clearly have a cyclic dependencies that Dagger will error out about. Usually this smells like bad design, but sometimes its not doable differently, in case you need something at runtime.

In these cases, work with `Lazy` injections, i.e. either

```
@Inject
Lazy<BannerManager> mLazyBannerManager;
...
mLazyBannerManager.get().doSomething();
```

or

```
IAdvertiumChecker providerAdvertiumChecker(Lazy<BannerManager> lazyBannerManager) {
    return new AdverticumChecker(lazyBannerManager);
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks a lot, to pass args trough constructor and use lazy injection seems to me it works. But now I'm a little bit confused. How can I decide when I have to pass args at contructor and when to use @Inject to inject dependency?

Comment: If you do not hide your implementations with interfaces, you can simply annotate a class' constructor with `@Inject` and Dagger2 uses this constructor to create the class. In such a constructor, you then either add (and bind) all arguments yourself (i.e. `@Inject public Foo(Bar bar, Baz baz);`) or you use an empty constructor and annotate all the injectable members again with `@Inject`.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I can now go on with your help. Anyway I have one more question at this time. I used singletone classes in my app, and I used synchronized methods in these calsses. But since I let dagger create singleton, if my methods are sychnronized they terminate work. But when I remove synchronized keyword, the work. I mustn't use synchronized methods in singletone classes if I create singletones with dagger?

Comment: The usage of DI with Dagger and the usage of `synchronized` has nothing to do with each other. You must face a different problem here.